# The argument type 'Set<dynamic Function(dynamic)>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)>'

Tags: flutter

Error happens under the comment
I am trying to implement firebase in my app on flutter.

```
import 'package:auduo/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auduo/opening_Screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // The error happens with the AppRoutes.define()
      routes: AppRoutes.define(),
      home: OpeningScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT  - Added routes file code
routes.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auduo/login_Screen.dart';
import 'package:auduo/register_Screen.dart';

class AppRoutes {
  AppRoutes._();

  static const String authLogin = '/auth-login';
  static const String authRegister = '/auth-register';

  static Set<Function(dynamic context)> define() {
    return {
          (context) => Login(), //authRegister(context) => Register(),     
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The provided code is main.dart

Comment: error is coming from routes, please share routes file code.

Comment: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auduo/login_Screen.dart';
import 'package:auduo/register_Screen.dart';

class AppRoutes {
  AppRoutes._();

  static const String authLogin = '/auth-login';
  static const String authRegister = '/auth-register';

  static Set<Function(dynamic context)> define() {
    return {
      (context) => Login(),
      //authRegister(context) => Register(),
    };
  }
}
`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Routes as

```
class AppRoutes {
  /// Set routes  name here
  static String authLogin ='/auth-login';

  /// Add entry for new route here
  static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> get routes {
    return {
      authLogin: (context) => const Login(),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Ill try it and let you know if it works, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auduo/login_Screen.dart';
import 'package:auduo/register_Screen.dart';

class AppRoutes {
  AppRoutes._();

  static const String authLogin = '/auth-login';
  static const String authRegister = '/auth-register';

  static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> get routes {
    return {
      authLogin: (context) => Login(),
      //(context) => Login(),
      //authRegister(context) => Register(),
    };
  }
}
`

Comment: how do you get the code to look the way you commented it?

Comment: Still giving the same error, keep in mind that I am very new to flutter/dart and won't understand all terminologies associated with it, so bear with me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
//routes.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auduo/login_Screen.dart';
import 'package:auduo/register_Screen.dart';

class AppRoutes {
  AppRoutes._();

  static const String authLogin = '/auth-login';
  static const String authRegister = '/auth-register';

  // Map<String>, not Set<Function>
  // define(), not get routes
  static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> define() {
    return {
      authLogin: (context) => Login(),
      authRegister: (context) => Register(),
    };
  }
}

//main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auduo/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:auduo/opening_Screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      //Have to type AppRoutes.define
      routes: AppRoutes.define(),
      home: OpeningScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```